# Use lag in spark sql within case statement

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a table like below

[image]

I want to add a `seq_group` column to the right based on the value of `stay` within each `Item` group.

[image]

For each Item group, `seq_group` starts with 0 and when `seq_group > 8600` it is set as previous row `seq_group + 1`, the else clause would be that the previous row `seq_group` is set.

I have implemented this in spark sql as below.

```
select 
Item,
Stay,
case when Stay > 8600
then lag(seq_group,1) over (partition by Item order by ts) + 1
else lag(seq_group,1) over (partition by Item order by ts)
end as seq_group
from tableA
```

and currently is getting the result as below

[image]

Any pointers to fix this would be of real help

Comment: Did you try perhaps prividing offset to lag function? lag(seq_group, 1)

Comment: @LiorChaga Sorry that was a typo. It was with the offset only

Comment: Ok, so I believe that the issue with the original query is that you actually have two different windows. It should work if you declared the window explicitly and just call the two lag function over the same window. But you already got a valid answer anyway...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be accomplished with a running sum.

```
select Item,
       Stay,
       sum(case when Stay > 8600 then 1 else 0 end) over(partition by item order by ts) as seq_group
from tableA
```